# Aurelia - Unable to access variables in my template

Tags: aurelia

Simple question.

I have a login template - a form for username and password:

```
<template>
<section>
    <h2>${heading}</h2>

    <form role="form" submit.delegate="login()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="userName">User Name</label>
            <input type="text" value.bind="userName" class="form-control" id="userName" placeholder="User Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" value.bind="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <button type="button"  click.delegate="submitLogin()" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
    </form>

    <hr>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" if.bind="loginError">${loginError}</div>
</section>
```

I have looked around to find out how I can access these variables in my login.ts file.

In particular I want to eventually send them to the api once the button login has been pressed.

I have a submitLogin() function but I dont know how you access the variables username and password.

Can someone show me how these variable are accessed.

I get a red underscore for username and password..

```
        import { HttpClient } from "aurelia-fetch-client";
        import { autoinject } from "aurelia-framework";
        import { TokenService } from "../tokenService";

        @autoinject
        export class Login {
            http: HttpClient;
          tokenService: TokenService;

          heading = "Login";


          constructor(tokenService: TokenService, http: HttpClient, ) {
            this.tokenService = tokenService;
            this.http = http;
          }

          public submitLogin(): void {


              console.log("userName, Password", this. userName, this.password);
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

form submit logic can be bound to `<form>` itself having given the button type `submit`

```
<form  role="form" submit.delegate="submitLogin()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">User Name</label>
        <input type="text" value.bind="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="User Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" value.bind="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
</form>
```

you can make your class fields accessible from the view or otherwise as below

```
import { HttpClient } from "aurelia-fetch-client"
import { autoinject } from "aurelia-framework"
import { TokenService } from "../tokenService"

@autoinject
export class Login {
    heading: string = "Login"
    username: string = ''
    password: string = '' // these are pubic fields available in your view unless you add 'private' in front of them

    constructor(private tokenService: TokenService, private http: HttpClient) { // this way you can keep them private since they are not needed in the view

    }

    submitLogin() {
        const { username, password } = this
        if (!!username && !!password) { // or your validations
            this.tokenService.login({ username, password })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. This really was a concise answer. Thankyou